# Google Authentication in Iframe - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, api, iframe, laravel-4

I'm using Google authentication in one of my application. Everything works fine, but when I tried to include the application URL in an Iframe it shows the following message,

[image]

I'm using Laravel 4.2, after searching for the solution I got following solutions.

Comment the following line in (/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/FrameGuard.php)

```
$response->headers->set('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN', false);
```

Or add following line in bootstrap/start.php

```
$app->forgetMiddleware('Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard');
```

Tried this methods and still the error is showing and authenticate with Google not working.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the header on your server has no impact on the response of the google server which explicitly denies loading in an iframe. Why don't you do the regular server-side OAuth handshake in the top frame? This redirects to google, the user authenticates and google redirects back to your site with an access token.

Comment: Did you mean adding the authentication logic in the parent website (where this particular app is added inside iframe)? If yes, I don't have control over the parent website. That is the issue.

Comment: How about a popup? You can have the same flow but open a popup which is closed at the end of the oauth dance. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent